# Wifi doesn't connect and i always need to use modprobe b43 to see wireless networks

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, wifi-hardware-switch

I use a broadcom b4313 wireless adapter and its switch doesn't on unless   `modprobe b43`   and also when connecting to a wireless network, i put the right password, it loads and show me the dialog again to input password. I have only been able to use ethernet.

I tried using `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

And this is the result of the command in the link below

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UtSg.png) <- Image link

Comment: Remove the driver you installed

Comment: How do i do that please

Comment: `sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-dkms` then reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 I still got this issue even after installing a fresh Debian distro on this computer. NB: bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-dkms  packages aren't installed